# Unity3d Error FacebookSDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have face with this error log when I try to get Build

```
stderr[
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/values/values.xml:131: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar'.

/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/values/values.xml:136: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.

]
```

Comment: Please see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287846/1205590

Answer (score 0):

From your android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support folder, copy 'appcombat-vX' and 'support-v4' folders to Library folder of your project (Not to Assets folder, it is different).

Comment: *support-v4-25.3.1.arr
is already added in project Assets>Plugins>Android Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the thing to do is to remove that old SDK and get the latest version from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/download#unity

Current version is 7.10.1.